# Android Kotlin - making link in TextView clickable

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

In strings.xml I have for the keyword

`by_continuing_you_agree_terms_and_policy`

the string

`By continuing, you agree our Terms of Service and <a href="https://www.google.com">Privacy Policy</a>`

This is the TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/createAccountTermsText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/by_continuing_you_agree_terms_and_policy"
    android:textColor="#A1A1A1" />
```

but nothing happens when I tap it.

Based on the "solutions" in other questions I added

```
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:linksClickable="true"
```

doesn't work too so I added:

```
binding.createAccountTermsText.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

doesn't work too!

This is not the first idiocy I see with Android SDK. Android seems to be a very horrendous software to develop apps for, period

Comment: "This is not the first idiocy I see with Android SDK. Android seems to be a very horrendous software to develop apps for, period" - you're free to not work on Android, you know.

Comment: Yeah because it's easy not to since half of phone users have android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright this is the full solution:

```
    val text = getString(R.string.by_continuing_you_agree_terms_and_policy)
    val ss = SpannableString(text)

    val clickTerms: ClickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(widget: View) {
            Log.d(tagg, "terms clicked")
            binding.createAccountTermsText.clearFocus()
        }
    }

    val clickPrivacy: ClickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(widget: View) {
            Log.d(tagg, "privacy clicked")
            binding.createAccountTermsText.clearFocus()
        }
    }
    
    val hintColorOne = ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"))
    val hintColorTwo = ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"))

    ss.setSpan(hintColorOne, 29, 45, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    ss.setSpan(hintColorTwo, 50, 64, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

    ss.setSpan(clickTerms, 29, 45, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    ss.setSpan(clickPrivacy, 50, 64, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

    binding.createAccountTermsText.text = ss
    binding.createAccountTermsText.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

the ints are standing for first/last characters, which means the color and click area is between them.

Note 1: using hintColorOne and hintColorTwo instead of like hintColorOne for both spans is necessary, because using only one for both spans would make only the second span work. It's just plain happiness to develop android apps with all those surprises!

Note 2: Using clickableSpan will disable the defined color and make use of the in the XML defined `android:textColorLink="#FF0000"` instead

Answer (score 1):

```
    android:autoLink="web"
```

makes something like `http://www.google.com` in the text clickable. Not `<a href="https://www.google.com">Privacy Policy</a>`

If you want use "a href" you need in code

```
val html=getString(R.string.linked_string)
textview.movementMethod=LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
textview.text=Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
```

in string.xml replace `<` with `&lt;`

Don't forget turn off `android:autoLink="web"`.

Comment: Thanks but I still need clicklisteners on those words